# How to match the last n children with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

We would like to match the last 12 elements of a parent container. How to do this with CSS? To clarify, 12 is an arbitrary number. We would like to know how to match the last N elements of a parent container.

Comment: Hint: not with `:nth-child()`.

Comment: 12 sounds like a very magic number. It'd be wiser to rethink exactly *why* you want 12.

Comment: 12 is an arbitrary number. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Crashalot Then maybe rename your question to "the last *n* children"? It will be better for a future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definetely [**:nth-last-child(N)**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastchild)

```
li:nth-last-child(-n+12) {
  /*your css declarations*/
}
```

This example selector will match the last 12 list items in any list, be it ordered or unordered:

Comment: But it doesn't support IE 8. And this is not valid CSS.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov True! IE8 doesn't support CSS3 pseudo classes and this question is tagged with CSS3

Comment: @Dipacks Fair enough. But what about non-valid CSS? My suggestion: make second line a comment: `/* declarations */`.

Comment: @Pavlo Mykhalov: You can always edit it, you know. It just so happens that SitePoint uses a vertical ellipsis in place of a proper comment for some reason.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't want the bad practice to be transitioned to SO. About the editing: it feels kinda wrong.

Answer (score 2):

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastchild

```
li:nth-last-child(-n+12) {
  ⋮ declarations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the `:nth-last-child` [pseudoclass](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses) (or `:nth-last-of-type` for type-checking).  After that you can use `~` to select all subsequent siblings:

`.container > *:nth-last-child(13) ~ * {  }`

http://jsbin.com/uhuzer/1/edit

Comment: And does not work if there arn't more children then you want.

Comment: More specifically, it doesn't work if there are fewer than 13 children. Of course, if the OP can guarantee that there will always be at least 13 children, then there won't be any issues.